# How to Auto-start selenium nodes under Windows

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, autostart

I am trying to automate the startup of my Selenium Grid.

I have the Hub registered as a service, so that starts when the machine starts, but
the literature tells me I can't do the same with the node, because it won't be in a User context, and so I would not be able to get screenshots etc.

I've seen vague hints that you can add something to the registry to start a program, but I'm not really convinced thats what I want.

IT pulls down the servers for upgrades at intervals, and sessions are set to time out after X amount of inactivity, so its a tedious and silly process to open remote desktops to all 6 nodes, in order to log in, then start the process every time.

How do you best manage this?
- Configure the machines to auto-login, and place startSeleniumNode.bat in that users start-folder?
- Add some kind of commandline entry in the jenkins build script that launches the test, to call each of the 6 nodes in turn to start the selenium node (and how would you do that?)

Comment: What did you settle on for your solution?

Comment: I never got around to fixing it. But I did verify that AlwaysUp would solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) - it allows you to run almost any application as a Windows service including Selenium Grid hubs and nodes.

I've previously created a fairly large Grid infrastructure using AlwaysUp for node management.  It's very useful for starting up Grid on boot and lets you specify a user account to run as, schedule restarts at regular intervals and a lot more.

Comment: Thanks; I will check that out. It seems to overcome the Session-0 problem of NSSM or SrvAny.

Comment: Is there a link you can provide to elaborate on the Session-0 problem?

Comment: Sure, http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation

It basically means, that if you start the selenium grid as a service (with srvany and System account), it won't be able to spawn UI elements, and you won't have much fun.